# How to differentialte between post and other requests in Django custom serialisers class

Tags: django

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):


    class Meta :
        model  =User
        validators = []
        ....
        ....

    def validate(self, data):
        ....
        .... 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ....
        .... 

    def update(self ,instance, validated_data):
        ....
```

Here is serialiser defined for a userModel. When this I hit this api the validate always run before create for Post or update for Put is called. I want to make some checks in the validate depending on Post or Put or any other method.

Is there a way to do so

Comment: you can access it inside validate method using `self.context['request'].method`

Comment: Thanks for the information. It worked perfectly.